# How to use uppercase depending on html lang dynamically changed by react-helmet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-i18next, react-helmet

In my application, I change the language by clicking buttons. Now I want to change and make some words uppercase depending on that language's uppercase rules. I tried to do this by changing the `<html/>` lang attribute dynamically. My language options are turkish and english

To change the html tag, I use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) and to translate the words I use [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) . It seems like working for some codes, but for some words, uppercase rules apply depending on the previous language.

```
<Helmet htmlAttributes={{lang: currentlySelectedLanguage}} />
```

```
function getHeader(){
   return[
     { id: headerOne, label: t("kit")}
   ]

}
```

t is a translator function from `react-i18n`. This function checks the translation json file of currentlySelectedLanguage and writes its value as the label.

Header item has `text-transform:uppercase` in its css class.

In turkish, there are two types of letters: i -> İ and ı -> I.

When I select `english`,  happens but instead of writing `KIT`, I get `KİT`. Which is uppercase rule for turkish,  not english.

When I select `turkish`,  happens but then I get `KIT`, but it should be `KİT`, which is also uppercase rule for english

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Setting [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)'s `htmlAttributes` with current lang (as in your statement),

```
<Helmet htmlAttributes={{ lang: currentlySelectedLanguage }} />
```

does not affect the elements in the DOM (button, headings, ... etc.) which have `text-transform: uppercase;` CSS declaration.

I solved it by setting `document.documentElement.lang` immediately at the beginning of the triggered set language action:

```
    setLanguage(currentlySelectedLanguage) {
        if (document.documentElement) {
            document.documentElement.lang = currentlySelectedLanguage
        }

        // do other stuff ...
    }
```

Setting `<html lang="??">` this way to solve the problem does not discourage me of using React Helmet, I continue managing all of the changes to the document head with React Helmet.